Without Reload data isn't fetching
I am using this package to load nationalities npm i i18n-nationality-updated
import { getNames } from 'i18n-nationality-updated'; 

const nationalities = getNames('en');
console.log(nationalities);

But the problem is without reloading nationalities data is not fetching, why this problem occurs ?
I have tried using useeffect, async await but still wasn't able to solve
console result of nationalities before reload = { }
console result of nationalities after reload =
{
    AF: 'Afghan',
    AL: 'Albanian',
    DZ: 'Algerian',
    AD: 'Andorran',
    AO: 'Angolan',
    AG: 'Antiguans',
    AR: 'Argentinean',
    AM: 'Armenian',
    AU: 'Australian',
    AT: 'Austrian',
    AZ: 'Azerbaijani',
    BS: 'Bahamian',
    BH: 'Bahraini',
    BD: 'Bangladeshi',
...}

I am trying to use it in a form input
  <Controller
              name="nationality"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                  value={field.value}
                  onValueChange={(value) => field.onChange(value)}
                >
                  <SelectTrigger className="bg-[#FAFAFA] text-[#222222] font-normal rounded-lg p-3 h-14 my-2 placeholder:pl-3 z-50 placeholder:font-normal text-[16px]">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select Nationality" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    {
                    Object.keys(nationalities).map((code, idx) => (
                    <SelectItem key={idx} value={nationalities[code]}>
                                                           {nationalities[code]}
                                            </SelectItem>
                    ))
                    }

                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              )}
            />

